# Kendo line chart X-axis displaying wrong date format

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-chart

My line chart shows wrong date format for the X-axis label. It is showing `/Date(1425148200000)/`, but I want it to show as `dd/MM/yyyy`.

This is my code:

```
.CategoryAxis(axis => axis.Categories(model => model.Price.EffectiveDate))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I handled this in the client side (javascript).

In client code, you need to instance a Date object passing this value 1425148200000 to the constructor, like:

```
var x = new Date(1425148200000)
```

here's what x will look like afterwards:

```
Sat Feb 28 2015 20:30:00 GMT+0200 (Jerusalem Standard Time)
```

Then you just need to format it as you wish.
(you can use the following date object methods to return a string in a DD/MM/YYYY format:

```
x.getDate()  // returns 28
x.getMonth() // returns 1
x.getFullYear()  // returns 2015
```

Alternatively, you may opt to display a string field in the grid, instead of the date value itself, which value would be the return of "toShortDateString()" on your DateTime object.

Comment: So, I called a javascript function using '.Template' as   .CategoryAxis(axis => axis
.Categories(model => model.Price.MedispanEffectiveDate)           .Labels(labels=>labels.Template("#=dateFuntion(Price.MedispanEffectiveDate)#"))) and in script part as function dateFuntion(date) {
    var date = new Date(parseInt(date.substr(6)));
       return date;
    }... Still not working...

Comment: Ok... I changed my code in backend...Used `ToShortDateString()`. So, returning Price.MedispanEffectiveDate.ToShortDateString(); (string)... Thanx Veverke..